# Obtaining the total charge density from a multi-species many-body wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics

One can exactly solve the two-body wavefunction describing the interaction of an electron and proton through the following Hamiltonian

$$H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_p}\nabla^2_{p} + -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}\nabla^2_{e} -\frac{e^2}{\vert \mathbf{r}_p-\mathbf{r}_e\vert}$$

The resulting two-particle wavefunction is then a function of both the electron and proton coordinates $\psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)$. The strange thing about this wavefunction is that it describes the probability amplitude of both the electron and proton, which have different charge. However, textbooks often ignore this fact, and state the the total charge density is given by $\vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)\vert^2$. This cannot possibly be correct, because if we integrate the total charge density over all space we should get identically zero for the electron-proton system.

My question is: what is the correct method for obtaining the charge density of a many-body wavefunction which has different charge species contained in it? If it were purely a wavefunction of electrons, then you could look at the one-body density matrix which contains all the information you need:

$$n(\mathbf{r}_1) = -Ne\int d\mathbf{r}_2...d\mathbf{r}_k \vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,...,\mathbf{r}_k)\vert^2$$

But what is the correct procedure for multi-species wavefunctions (i.e. wavefunctions of particles with different charge/quantum numbers)? Naively I would assume the charge density is given by the following equation, but I am not sure if this is rigorously true.

$$\rho(\mathbf{r}) = +e\left(\int d\mathbf{r}_e \vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)\vert^2\right)\rvert_{\mathbf{r}_p=\mathbf{r}} -e\left(\int d\mathbf{r}_p \vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)\vert^2\right) \rvert_{\mathbf{r}_e=\mathbf{r}}$$

Comment: Somewhat related: [QM Continuity Equation: Many-Body Version for Density Operator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294837/qm-continuity-equation-many-body-version-for-density-operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your final expression,
$$\rho(\mathbf{r}) = +e\left(\int d\mathbf{r}_e \vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)\vert^2\right)\rvert_{\mathbf{r}_p=\mathbf{r}} -e\left(\int d\mathbf{r}_p \vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)\vert^2\right) \rvert_{\mathbf{r}_e=\mathbf{r}},$$
is indeed correct, but it's more helpful to rephrase it in the form
$$
\rho(\mathbf{r}) 
=
\sum_{j=p,e}
\int d\mathbf{r}_e  d\mathbf{r}_p \:
q_j \delta (\mathbf r-\mathbf r_j) \:
\vert \psi(\mathbf{r}_p,\mathbf{r}_e)\vert^2,
$$
which makes it much more obvious how to connect it to a full formal operator expectation value, namely
$$
\rho(\mathbf r) = \langle \psi | \hat \rho(\mathbf r) |\psi\rangle
$$
where
$$
\hat \rho(\mathbf r) = \sum_{j=p,e} q_j \delta (\mathbf r-\hat {\mathbf r}_j).
$$
This operator version is then the obvious quantum-mechanical version of the classical charge density $\rho(\mathbf r) = \sum_{j=p,e} q_j \delta (\mathbf r-{\mathbf r}_j)$ of two point charges $q_e$ and $q_p$ at positions $\mathbf r_e$ and $\mathbf r_p$, respectively.

And, of course, it generalizes transparently to the case of $N$ particles, both distinguishable and indistinguishable, and it reduces to the (correct) formula you give for indistinguishable particles when you do have the symmetry in place.

Answer (score 1):

> Textbooks often ... state the the total charge density is given by $|\psi({\bf r}_p,{\bf r}_e)|^2$. This cannot possibly be correct, because if we integrate the total charge density over all space we should get identically zero for the electron-proton system.

Any textbook making this claim (do you have an example?) is *seriously* confused. First of all, $|\psi({\bf r}_p,{\bf r}_e)|^2$ isn't a charge density at all, but rather a probability density. Second of all, even if you multiply by $e$, then $e |\psi({\bf r}_p,{\bf r}_e)|^2$ still isn't a *spatial* charge density; it's a charge density over *configuration* space, which is conceptually very different. For example, spatial charge densities have dimension charge/volume, while for an $n$-particle system, configuration-space charge densities have dimension charge/(volume)$^n$.

Probably the best way to physically interpret the quantity $e |\psi({\bf r}_p,{\bf r}_e)|^2$ is to hold ${\bf r}_p$ fixed and think of it as a function $e |\psi_{{\bf r}_p}({\bf r}_e)|^2$ of a *single* (vector) argument. In this case, the function can be roughly thought of as the *conditional* spatial charge density of the electron alone *given* the location of the proton (up to a sign that depends on your conventions).

(You could of course instead hold ${\bf r}_e$ fixed and consider $e |\psi_{{\bf r}_e}({\bf p}_e)|^2$ as the proton's charge density conditioned on the electron's location, but this is much less useful because the proton is so much heavier that in practice its wavefunction is much more localized than the electron's, so in order to understand atomic (as opposed to nuclear) physics you can treat it as a classical point particle.)

The interpretation of a "conditional spatial density" is a bit subtle; note that it doesn't have the units of a true spatial density, and in order to convert it into a true spatial density you need to integrate it with respect to the parameter ${\bf r}_p$ over some possible volume $V_p$ where the proton could be located. Integrating ${\bf r}_p$ over all space (the second term in your expression) gives the marginal charge density of the election alone, with no restrictions on the proton's location.

Your full expression for $\rho({\bf r})$ (with the obvious generalization for more species) is indeed the correct expectation value for the total charge density operator at point ${\bf r}$, which is the most natural way to assign a "spatial charge density" to the system. But note that even in the single-particle case, naively considering $e |\psi({\bf r})|^2$ as a charge density is a useful heuristic but can be a bit dangerous; a wavefunction is fundamentally quantum mechanical, and an electron maintains a particle-like nature in certain senses. (E.g. if you precisely measure its location then you'll always observe it to be localized; you'll never measure it to simultaneously be on opposite sides of the nucleus, as with a classical charged fluid.)

Comment: I should be more precise, textbooks will separate the wavefunction into relative and c.o.m. parts, with the relative part $\vert\psi(r_e-r_p)\vert^2$ given the role of the charge density. It is inherently assumed that the proton has a (classically) fixed position so r_p=const. That's practically true, but if one were to look at the case of an electron and positron (or muon), where that assumption breaks down, then the well known hydrogen orbitals do *not* describe the charge density nor position of the electron.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the charge density can be written as an operator that obeys all the usual Heisenberg time evolution, so it really isn't that dangerous right?

Comment: Actually after thinking about it, would the formula be derivable from $\rho= \Sigma Z_i \psi^{\dagger}_i(r) \psi_i(r')$ and the canonical commutation relations for fermions $[\psi^{\dagger}_i(r),\psi_i(r')]=\delta_{r,r'}$

Comment: @user157879 Writing the wavefunction as $\psi({\bf r}_c - {\bf r}_p)$ with ${\bf r}_p$ a fixed constant completely changes its interpretation, and even its units, so that's a very different question. In that case it's just a one-particle wavefunction and the effective charge density for the *electron* is indeed just $e |\psi({\bf r}_c - {\bf r}_p)|^2$ with no integration needed.

Comment: sure but while the relative coordinate wavefunction is still valid for an electron-positron system and is a traditional hydrogen orbital, there the interpretation would no longer be the effective charge density of electron right?

Comment: @user157879 Right, but they can easily be converted back to an effective charge density by using the standard formulas to go from relative to absolute coordinates. The orbitals are the same as for the hydrogen atom, up to a replacement of $m_e$ with the reduced mass, the doubling of the kinetic energy to incorporate positron motion, shifting from relative to absolute coordinates, etc.

Comment: @user157879 It's perfectly fine to think of $e |\psi({\bf r})|^2$ as a charge density, as long as you remember that it's a *quantum* charge density and there are associated subtleties.

Comment: thanks! But just one last question, I've never seen anyone convert the relative wavefunction into an absolute one that is only a function of r_e (by integrating out r_p), what do you mean by standard trick then? I know about replacing m by $mu$ in the energy, bohr radius, etc. but have never seen a $\rho(r_e)$ obtained from the relative wavefunction

Comment: @user157879 All I'm saying is that if you have a wavefunction written in the form $\psi({\bf r}_e - {\bf r}_p)$, then you (a) first convert it into a wavefunction $\psi({\bf r}_e, {\bf r}_p)$ of two arguments using the [standard formulas from classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem#Energy_of_the_two-body_system) for going from relative to absolute coordinates, then (b) integrate the joint probability distribution $|\psi({\bf r}_e, {\bf r}_p)|^2$ with respect to ${\bf r}_p$ to get the marginal probability distribution for the electron position.

Comment: @user157879  You can also multiply that latter probability distribution by $q_e$ if you want to turn it into an effective charge density due to the electron.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77591/discussion-between-user157879-and-tparker).

Comment: @user157879 Has this answer addressed your question?

Comment: the first half of the discussion is irrelevant as we discussed in the chat,  because I'm not confused by the meaning of these wavefunctions. Nonetheless, I would accept the answer if you add in the derivation of the form of the charge density starting from the definition of charge density in terms of field operators or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The charge density is the probability of finding a particle at position $\vec r$, regardless of where the other particles are. For the wave function above this is $\int{ d\vec r' (e |\psi(\vec r,\vec r') |^2 - e |\psi(\vec r',\vec r )|^2})$. For an $n$-particle wave function this is $\sum_{i=1}^n{ q_i \int{ d\vec r_1 .. d\vec r_{i-1} d\vec r_{i+1} .. d\vec r_n |\psi(\vec r_1,..,\vec r_{i-1},\vec r,\vec r_{i+1}..,\vec r_n |^2} }$. The $q_i$ have to be factored in manually in the Schrödinger - also in the Dirac - picture.

Triggered by tparkers answer: $|\psi(\vec r_p,\vec r_e) |^2$ gives the joint probability of finding the proton at $\vec r_p$ and the electron at $\vec r_e$.