# Derivation of current density operator using Heisenberg equation of motion

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian

Electronic (probability) current density is calculated by continuity equation:
$$
\nabla\cdot \vec J=-\partial_t \rho \tag{1}
$$
here $\vec J$ is current density operator and $\rho=e \psi_r^+\psi_r$ is density.
One way to find $\vec J$ is to explicitly calculate time derivative of $\rho$ and use Schrodinger equation. This method is explained [here](https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/qmcurrent.pdf). This method is easy to understand for me.

I am trying to calculate $\vec J$ using Heisenberg equation of motion that is
$$
\nabla\cdot \vec J = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H_0,e\psi_{r'}^+\psi_{r'}]\tag{2}
$$
I am stuck at calculation of this commutation relation. I take $H_0$ as Hamiltonian of free particle:
$$
H_0 = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d\vec r \nabla \psi_{r}^+ \nabla \psi_{r} \tag{3}
$$
So:
$$
[H_0,e\psi_{r'}^+\psi_{r'}]= [H_0,\psi_{r'}^+]\psi_{r'}+\psi_{r'}^+[H_0,\psi_{r'}]\tag{4}
$$
And
$$
[H_0,\psi_{r'}]=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d\vec r  [\nabla \psi_{r}^+ \nabla \psi_{r},\psi_{r'}]= \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d\vec r  \nabla \psi_{r}^+[ \nabla \psi_{r},\psi_{r'}] +\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d\vec r  [\nabla \psi_{r}^+ ,\psi_{r'}]\nabla \psi_{r} \tag{5}
$$
how to proceed? how to calculate $[\nabla \psi_{r}^+ ,\psi_{r'}]$?

---

**Edit 1:**

After a comment, i found that $[\nabla \psi_{r}^+ ,\psi_{r'}]=\nabla[ \psi_{r}^+ ,\psi_{r'}]$. After using commutation rules $[ \psi_{r} ,\psi_{r'}^+]=\delta(r-r')$, I get:
$$
\nabla\cdot \vec J = \frac{-i\hbar e}{2m}\int d\vec r \{\psi_r^+ (\nabla_r[\psi_r^+,\psi_{r'}])\nabla \psi_r +\nabla \psi_r^+ (\nabla[\psi_{r},\psi_{r'}^+])\psi_r\}\\
= \frac{-i\hbar e}{2m}\int d\vec r \{\psi_r^+ \nabla_r\delta(r-r')\nabla \psi_r +\nabla \psi_r^+ \nabla\delta(r-r')\psi_r\}\\
= \frac{-i\hbar e}{2m} \{\psi_r^+ \nabla^2 \psi_r +\nabla \psi_r^+ (\nabla)\psi_r\}
$$
The very term $\nabla\psi_r^+ (\nabla)\psi_r$, it should be $(\nabla^2\psi_r^+)\psi_r$. I wonder how the extra $\nabla$ moves back?

Comment: Hint $[\nabla_r \psi_r^\dagger, \psi_{r'}] = \nabla_r [\psi_r^\dagger,\psi_{r'}]$ where $\nabla_r$ is the derivative with respect to the $r$ coordinates (and not the $r'$s)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294837/qm-continuity-equation-many-body-version-for-density-operator

Comment: @BySymmetry thank you for quick reply. I have also solved it, except for one little confusion. I have written this is Edit1. Please have a look at it